# Existence and regularity of solutions to parabolic equation on domain with disjoint boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega$ be an open set with boundary such that $\partial\Omega = \Gamma_1 \cup \Gamma_2$ where $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ are closed and smooth but disconnected, in particular think of $\Omega$ to be an annulus.

I'm looking for existence and regularity results (in Sobolev or Sobolev-Bochner spaces) for parabolic equations of the form

$$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
$$u|_{\Gamma_1} = g$$
$$u|_{\Gamma_2} = h$$

and what kind of regularity is needed for $f, g, h$. Does anyone have a reference?